# Omitir Acentos en Busqueda ReciclerView

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación android en donde estoy llenando un reciclerview con los datos de una api y estoy implementando un filtro de búsqueda en el recicler pero como podría hacer para que al momento de buscar los datos me omita los acentos, lo que pasa es que los datos que vienen de la api son datos de personas y algunos nombres vienen con acentos entonces si en mi filtro(editext) escribo Jose y  en el recicler tiene José no me muestra registros entonces como hago para que independientemente si el usuario digita sin acentos me muestre los resultados.

esta es mi clase adaptador

```
public class Adaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptador.EmpleadoHolder>  {

    private Activity activity;
    private int recurso;
    private List<Empleado> lista;

    public Adaptador(Activity activity, int recurso, List<Empleado> lista ) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.recurso = recurso;
        this.lista = lista;
    }


    @Override
    public EmpleadoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(recurso,parent,false);
        return new EmpleadoHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EmpleadoHolder holder, int position) {
        //llenamos item
        Empleado e = lista.get(position);
        holder.txtcircle.setText(e.Nombre.charAt(0)+"");//asignamos primera Inicial Nombre
        holder.txtnombre.setText(e.Nombre +" "+e.Apllido);
        holder.txtcarnet.setText(e.Carnet);
        holder.id = e.Carnet;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lista.size(); //indicamos cuantos elementos hay que cargar en el reciclerView
    }



    public class EmpleadoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView txtcircle,txtnombre,txtcarnet;
        String id;

        public EmpleadoHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            //asigno datos de item
            txtcircle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_circle);
            txtnombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_nombre);
            txtcarnet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_carnet);

        }
    }

    //filtramos datos
    public void Filtrar(ArrayList<Empleado> filtroEmpleado){
        this.lista = filtroEmpleado;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

luego en mi mainActivity en mi oncreate tengo los siguientes eventos del editext para el filtro

```
  //para hacer Filtro textbox
    txtFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
        {
            filtrar(editable.toString());
        }
    });
```

y este es mi metodo para filtrar

```
//filtrar datos
public void filtrar(String texto){
    ArrayList<Empleado> filtrarLista = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Empleado empleado: list){
        String datos= empleado.Nombre+empleado.Apllido;//campos para filtrar
        if(datos.toLowerCase().contains(texto.toLowerCase())){
            filtrarLista.add(empleado);
        }
    }
    adaptador.Filtrar(filtrarLista);
}
```

Podrian orientarme de como resolver mi problema

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer la comprobación sin tener en cuenta los acentos puedes usar Collator te dejo un ejemplo de como usarlo:

```
    final Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();
    collator.setStrength(Collator.NO_DECOMPOSITION);

//En caso que sea igual a 0 es que son iguales.
    collator.compare(datos, texto);
```

Comment: gracias, y como lo implementaria en mi codigo en el metodo afterTextChanged o en donde?

Comment: Añádelo donde tenias actualmente la función en la que compara los valores en tu caso public void filtrar(String texto)